# What does Drush error "Unknown option: --db-url" mean?

Tags: drush

Somehow user 1 has become blocked on a Drupal site I manage.   As a result, I can't issue a uli command via Drush.  I tried to use the command

```
drush @pantheon.xxxxxx.dev user-unblock --uid=1
```

but it returns error

```
Unknown option: --db-url.  See `drush help user-unblock` for available options.
```

I have checked the help for user-unblock for but it does not mention --db-url.  The site is working and and other users can log in, however I can't get in as admin.

Thanks.

Comment: http://help.getpantheon.com/pantheon/topics/using_drush_60_pantheon_how_set_strict0_globally Looks similar?

Answer (score 3):

Pantheon site aliases are only compatible with Drush 5. I had the same message when trying to use Drush 6.

On a Mac with Homebrew, I ran "brew install drush5" and then symlinked the resulting file (/usr/local/Cellar/drush5/5.9/libexec/drush) to "/usr/local/bin/drush5" not to interfere with my existing Drush installation.

Now I can run commands such as "$ drush5 @pantheon.xxx uli" when needed for Pantheon.

Comment: Note for those not handy with the CLIs, symbolic link is created via "ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/drush5/5.9/libexec/drush /usr/local/bin/drush5"

Answer (score 3):

incase someone is trying to add -- to other drush commands you can use:

terminus drush site.env -- [drush command here] -- [drush option here]

the "--" after the site.env will pass the options to drush instead of terminus.

example: terminus drush $SITE_ID -- up -s --security-only

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing, Pantheon site aliases are [only compatible with Drush 5](https://github.com/westonruter/pantheon-documentation/blob/master/source/docs/articles/local/drush-command-line-utility.md).

If you're using a newer version of Drush (6, 7, 8+), you'll likely get the following message when trying to execute a Drush command with a Pantheon alias:

```
$ drush @pantheon.xxx.xxx status

Unknown option: --db-url. See `drush help pm-enable` for available [error]
options. To suppress this error, add the option --strict=0.
```

There are two possible workarounds:

1. Provide the option `--strict=0` to each Drush command

   `$ drush @pantheon.xxx.xxx status --strict=0`
2. Install Drush 5 and use it specifically with Pantheon

   If you're a Mac user and use [Homebrew](https://www.drupal.org/node/954766), the second option is as simple as:

   `$ brew install drush5`

   `$ ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/drush5/5.9/libexec/drush /usr/local/bin/drush5`

   `$ drush5 @pantheon.xxx.xxx user-login`

The first method works for me using Drush 8.1.9 and Drupal 7.53 (and optionally [Terminus](https://pantheon.io/docs/terminus/) 1.0.0) on macOS 10.12.3 "Sierra". I have not personally tested the second method.

*In either case, be sure your [Pantheon aliases are up-to-date](https://pantheon.io/docs/drush/#download-drush-aliases-locally):*

```
$ terminus aliases
[notice] Aliases file written to ~/.drush/pantheon.aliases.drushrc.php
```

Comment: This is an older question, so the later answer is more applicable. --strict=0 is the quickest and least confusing solution, imo.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fixing it directly in the database?  You should be able to `update users set status = 1 where uid = 1;`

If for whatever reason you cant do this, you can try running the query with drush: `drush sql-query "update users set status = 1 where uid = 1"`